# AVAudioEngine: failed: -10851 (enable 2... speech recognition crashes

Tags: ios, swift

I am having a strange issue when starting speech recognition from an isolated AVAudioEngine instance.

Premise:
1-The root view controller contains the AVAudioEngine instance used for speech recognition requests, based on the "speak to me" app example provided by apple.

2-The child view controller contains and instance of a SceneKit scene with its own audio engine which I stop and notify the root view controller about to start recognition as a completion block.

When I start recognition, here is the logs I get:

> starting recognition
>   recording format?
>   
>   format works
>   audio engine prepared
>   say something
>   2017-02-11 09:47:16.505795 Macaron[965:319461] [aurioc] 892: failed: -10851 (enable 2, outf< 2 ch,  48000 Hz, Float32, non-inter> inf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Float32, non-inter>)
>   2017-02-11 09:47:16.506783 Macaron[965:319461] [central] 54:   ERROR:    [0x16e1d7000] >avae> AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:2515: PerformCommand: error -10851
>   2017-02-11 09:47:16.508434 Macaron[965:319461] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'error -10851'

What I have noticed above is that the recording format is 1ch 44.1 khz float 32 de-interlaced which is one of the standard framerates. However, the output node seems to be at 48 khz. This does not seem to be a standard framerate. So I checked to see if any of my sound clips used in the SceneKit view controller had a different framrate (48 khz) but they are all the same, 44.1 khz.

I would expect that if an input node and other nodes in the audio graph have different framerates, this might cause a problem.

Alongside requesting some kind of explanation for this error, I also have a question:

Would it be better to refer the sceneKit audioEngine instance to start the speech recognition on?

Code here and how it works:

//In a subView of MainViewController
NotificationCenter.default.post(startSpeechRecognition, object: nil)

//In the MainViewController

```
class MainViewController:UITabBarController, SFSpeechRecognizerDelegate{
    //Speech recognition
    private var recognitionRequest:SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest?
    private var speechRecognitionTask:SFSpeechRecognitionTask?
private let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    private var speechRecogniser:SFSpeechRecognizer!


    public  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let locale = NSLocale.current
speechRecogniser = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: locale)
        //Start observers for hardware input
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(checkEngine(_ :)), name: requestSpeechRecognition, object: nil)
    }

    public override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        speechRecogniser.delegate = self
        SFSpeechRecognizer.requestAuthorization {(authStatus) in
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                switch authStatus{
                case .authorized:
                    print("Speech recognition authorised")
                    synth.speechRecOn = true
                case .denied:
                    print("speech recognition has been denied")
                case .notDetermined:
                    print("speech recognition not determined")
                case .restricted:
                    print("speech recognition is restricted")
                }
            }
        }
    }


    func checkEngine(_ notification: Notification){
if audioEngine.isRunning{
            audioEngine.stop()
            recognitionRequest?.endAudio()
        }else{
            AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission(){ [unowned self] allowed in
                    if allowed{
                        print("starting recognition")
                        self.startRecognition()
                }else{
                        return
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func startRecognition(){
        if let speechRecognitionTask = speechRecognitionTask{
            speechRecognitionTask.cancel()
            self.speechRecognitionTask = nil
        }

        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do{
            try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord)
            try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement)
            try audioSession.setActive(true, with: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
        }catch {
            print("something's wrong with the audio session")
        }
        recognitionRequest = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()
        guard let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode else{
            fatalError("Audio engine has no input node")
        }
        guard let recognitionRequest = recognitionRequest else{
            fatalError("Unable to create a speech recognition buffer request")
        }
        recognitionRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = true
        speechRecognitionTask = speechRecogniser.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest, resultHandler: { (result, error) in
            var isFinal = false
            if let result = result{
                print("there's a result")
                spoken.append(result.bestTranscription.formattedString)
                isFinal = (result.isFinal)
            }
            if error != nil || isFinal{
                self.audioEngine.stop()
                inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
                self.recognitionRequest = nil
                self.speechRecognitionTask = nil
            }
        })
        let recordingFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
        print("recording format?")
        print(recordingFormat)
        print("format works")
        inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat){(buffer, when) in
            print("adding recording to buffer")
            self.recognitionRequest?.append(buffer)
        }
        audioEngine.prepare()
        print("audio engine prepared")
        do{
            try audioEngine.start()
            print("say something")
        }catch {
            print("something wrong with result")
        }
    }

private func confirmAndSetValue(){
    }

    func speechRecognizer(_ speechRecognizer: SFSpeechRecognizer, availabilityDidChange available: Bool) {
        if available{
            print("recogniser is available")
        }else{
            print("Recogniser is not available")
        }
    }


}
```

Again, the sample rate for the audio engine is 48khz while the input tap is 41 khz. I read on AVAudioEngine that the main mixer node is responsible for dynamically switching sample rates and other properties, but I'm not sure whether the tap goes through that mixer node (though I assume this is by default?)

Comment: Here's a link to a short description for that error: https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=10851. It sounds like one of your `AUAudioUnit`s is not set up correctly.

Comment: The problem is that I have no audio units set, just a mic tap in on the input node.

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: Hey Dave, updated the question with relevant code. Sorry about the delay